# HTTP post request to a php server from ionic 2 front end

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my code in `sign-up.ts`

```
let link = "http://localhost/signup.php";
    this.http.post(link, signupdata)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Success");
      },error => {
        console.log("Error");
      });
```

when I submit the form I get the following error in my console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/signup.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Help me in solving this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by installing chrome extension [**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: ***](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

*How it works:*

[image]

**Note:** You have to disable this when you use other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines into the top of your signup.php script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: Great - glad to help. Don't forget to up vote my answer ;-)